# Custom UITableViewCell is empty, although cell from heightForRowAtIndexPath is correct

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Sorry, I am missing it. I have a beautiful table with correct (variable) row heights. But all the cells are blank. Three labels should be populated in each cell.

**UPDATE: FIX IS BELOW**

```
@implementation MasterTableCell 

@synthesize labelDesc;
@synthesize labelDuration;
@synthesize labelName;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (self) {


    // name
    CGRect frameTextLabel = CGRectMake(8, 2, 244, 25);
    labelName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameTextLabel];
    labelName.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    labelName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    labelName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // description
    labelDesc = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    labelDesc.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    labelDesc.numberOfLines = 0;
    labelDesc.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    labelDesc.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    labelDesc.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    // duration
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(252, 5, 40, 20);
    labelDuration = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    labelDuration.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.f ];
    labelDuration.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    labelDuration.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // to see it

    [self.contentView addSubview:labelName];
    [self.contentView addSubview:labelDesc];
    [self.contentView addSubview:labelDuration];

  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

And

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

  MasterTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
   {
    cell = [[MasterTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

  Recipe *recipeAtIndex = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  cell.labelName.text = @"Test1";
  cell.labelDesc.text = @"Test2";
  cell.labelDuration.text = [TBCommon formattedStringforDuration:recipeAtIndex.duration withDelimeter:@":"];

  CGRect frameDescLabel = CGRectMake(8, 25, 284, [self heightForDescriptionFrame:recipeAtIndex.description]);
  cell.labelDesc.frame = frameDescLabel;

  return cell;
}
```

**FIX**

```
#import "MasterTableCell.h"

@implementation MasterTableCell : UITableViewCell

@synthesize labelDesc;
@synthesize labelDuration;
@synthesize labelName;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

// name
CGRect frameTextLabel = CGRectMake(8, 2, 244, 25);
labelName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameTextLabel];
labelName.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
labelName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
labelName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// description
labelDesc = [[UILabel alloc] init];
labelDesc.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
labelDesc.numberOfLines = 0;
labelDesc.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
labelDesc.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];

// duration
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(252, 5, 40, 20);
labelDuration = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
labelDuration.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:38.0/255.0 green:111.0/255.0 blue:208.0/255.0 alpha:1];
labelDuration.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.f ];
labelDuration.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

[self.contentView addSubview:labelName];
[self.contentView addSubview:labelDesc];
[self.contentView addSubview:labelDuration];
}

@end
```

And

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

MasterTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Recipe *recipeAtIndex = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.labelName.text = recipeAtIndex.name;
cell.labelDesc.text = recipeAtIndex.description;
cell.labelDuration.text = [TBCommon formattedStringforDuration:recipeAtIndex.duration withDelimeter:@":"];

CGRect frameDescLabel = CGRectMake(8, 25, 284, [self heightForDescriptionFrame:recipeAtIndex.description]);
cell.labelDesc.frame = frameDescLabel;

return cell;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked your cell identifier and spelling of it in xib or storyboard?

Comment: Also check your array, and make sure the `Recipe` item you are pulling out still has it's data.

Comment: Cell identifier looks good, I'm using Storyboards and I have the class for Custom Class set to `MasterTableCell`. I replaced the values from `Recipe` with static strings to make sure that's not an issue. :(

Comment: Is your ```UIViewController``` linked as your ```UITableView```'s ```dataSource```?

Comment: To clarify, you set the Custom Class to `MasterTableCell` when you had the cell selected, and the Custom Class of your ViewController is set to the class where `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is, right?

Comment: @GeneralMike: Yes, correct sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Storyboards, initWithStyle will never be called.  Move the label creation code into awakeFromNib.

You can get rid of the whole if (cell == nil) part too because dequeueReusableCell will ALWAYS return a cell.

Comment: I'm using initWithStyle in my storyboard program, and its seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: That was it! Never in a million years would I have thought to put the creation code in awakeFromNib. Wow. I will update above with the new version that is working. I don't understand why this works, will need to dig into it.

Comment: Any object that is loaded from a nib has its -awakeFromNib method called when it comes out of hibernation. This is one part where Apple's opaqueness I think is harmful - they don't explicitly say anywhere (that I'm aware of) that Storyboards are implemented behind-the-scenes with nibs, although it's an obvious conclusion to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that your table view delegate/datasource method are actually being called. Trying putting a break point in cellForRowAtIndexPath method to verify that. If breakpoint's not hit it means your delegate and datasource are not set. Set those.

Another thing that I noticed is that you have not set the frame for your labelDesc instance variable. That's worth looking at.

Comment: I noticed the frame thing too, but he sets it in his `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, instead of setting it in the `init` for the cell like the others - I don't think that is causing the issue.

Comment: Delegate and datasource are being used (the VC is a subclass of `UITableViewController`), if I `NSLog` the values for `recipeAtIndex.duration` (for example) all is well. I set the frame for `labelDesc` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because the height for this label depends on its content (maybe that's wrong way to do it?). This is working, the row heights are correct, the content is there just doesn't paint. I changed one of the labels to have a red background and don't see it.

Comment: Do you have your cell in the NIB file? If YES then you must load it like this: 
NSArray *items = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NibName owner:self options:nil];
cell = [items objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Using Storyboard but then programmatically configure the cell, @jsd reply fixed it, use `awakeFromNib`. But I don't use Nibs anywhere.

Comment: YES that's what I menat that if you use resource files initWithStyle will not be called. Never mind, happy that you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I was setting up my custom cell subclasses, the tutorial I was following had me set the frames in a separate method called `layoutSubviews`.  For you, it would look like

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    labelName.frame = CGRectMake(8, 2, 244, 25);
    labelDuration.frame = CGRectMake(252, 5, 40, 20);
}
```

When I had something to add to a cell that is dynamically located like `labelDesc` is, I had to totally pull it out of my custom cells class and put it all in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (so I would have something like `labelDesc = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame...` and so on all in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and nothing for it in the `initWithStyle`).

I don't know why doing it this way is any different than setting the frames in initWithStyle, but it seems to be working for me.